# Turning a text file into a list using prolog. Using the split_string predicate

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to use the split_string/4 predicate to turn a string into a list of strings. I want the string separated by each newline. This is what my code looks like

```
main(Argv) :-
   [InputFilename|OutputFileName] = Argv,
   read_file_to_string(InputFilename, InputFileString,[]),
   split_string(InputFileString,"\n", "\n", InputFileList),
   write(InputFileList).
```

But it is not writing anything to the console. However if I put

```
write(InputFileString)
```

It prints the contents of the file just fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

```
main(Input_filename,Output_filename) :-
   read_file_to_string(Input_filename, Input_string,[]),
   split_string(Input_string,"\n", "\n", Input_list),
   write(Input_list).
```

Example input file `C:/input_data.txt`

```
Line one
Line two
Line three
```

Example run

```
?- main('C:/input_data.txt','C:/output_data.txt').
[Line one,Line two,Line three]
true.
```

Your use of `|` in `[InputFilename|OutputFileName]` is for separating the head and the tail of a list. A simple change to using `,` to pass in two parameters is all that is needed, e.g. `main(Input_filename,Output_filename)`.

This answer also changed the style of the variable names to [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) which is customary with Prolog.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Argv` is a list with two or more elements, it **does not** unify with `[InputFilename|OutputFileName]` because this is not a list with two elements.

See:

```
$ swipl -q
?- [a,b] = [X|Y].
X = a,
Y = [b].

?- [a,b] = [X|Y], X = a, Y = b.
false.
```

If you know your list has exactly 2 elements, you can use `[X, Y]`. If your list could have 2 or more elements, you can use `[X, Y|_]`. Here:

```
?- [X,Y] = [a,b].
X = a,
Y = b.

?- [X,Y] = [a,b,c].
false.

?- [X,Y|_] = [a,b].
X = a,
Y = b.

?- [X,Y|_] = [a,b,c].
X = a,
Y = b.

?- [X,Y|_] = [a].
false.
```